# PHP Cannot upload file larger than 200MB

Tags: php, upload

On my site, I'm allowing file uploads. I've successfully uploaded a 180 MB file.
But I've been trying to upload a file that is 393MB, and every time, it fails at 51% upload (approx 200MB uploaded).  By "it fails" I mean that the file upload then restarts at 0%. Eventually, it gives up and Chrome tells me it lost connection with mysite.com and reload the page later.

In my php.ini, I have the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10G
post_max_size = 10G
max_execution_time = 60 
max_input_time = 10000 
memory_limit = -1
```

I know my max_execution_time is low, but according to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php):

> max_execution_time only affects the execution time of the script itself...time taken by the file upload process is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running.

I verified that my php.ini directives are set successfully via phpinfo();

I have a Linux Server with Godaddy with unlimited bandwidth and disk space. It's shared hosting, though I have a dedicated IP.

**EDIT:** I tried a 204MB file. It failed around 98 or 99%. So, it looks like I cannot go over 200MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I called Godaddy.
Max upload size that Godaddy allows on shared hosting is 192MB.

I would need to get a dedicated server or possibly go with a different provider.

Comment: I have to wonder why this is getting upvoted when it's something that should have been done before posting the question here.

Comment: Haha. Honestly, I agree with you. Maybe because I provided accurate and helpful information?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to upload such big files maybe you can try with ftp web access?

I dont know about the shared hosting but if you do have big site you better go with your own linux machine and configure it the way you find it appropriate.

**==Some updates on the last question==**

http://www.net2ftp.com/ this is ftp web access for example, but the deal is if your clients want to upload it will be headache to make each an ftp to specific folder, although it can be done.

Now as i never did this before i made some research and i found http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php, it will require an ftp user and password but you can have one for the site You need to look deep into the gaps you may open with this.

You will find in this page lots of ftp upload examples hope it helps else like you said you will need a server dedicated or virtual dedicated to try it, are you located in EU? i can help u test your app on one of my servers if you want... but still 200mb with only webupload without flash involved may lead to http session timeout.

I'm intrested in Flash upload in combination with FTP, so no session timeout ... ill keep searching.

Comment: The site's new, so it's not a huge concern yet, honestly. But I will get a dedicated server when the site has grown a bit and I can afford it - and eventually just purchase my own servers. But regarding FTP web access, I did some searching and couldn't find how to do that. Everything I found involved regular HTML form upload, then using FTP to transfer to an external server, which wouldn't work, because it's the HTML form upload portion that fails.

Comment: For the net2ftp, it looks like that would give my users far more control than I would like. Regarding [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php), I believe that first requires that the server have the file, which in the file upload case, would require the HTTP upload first.
I appreciate the offer, but I'm in the U.S. Later down the road, I'll have a dedicated server, or I may use a flash uploader that uses FTP. Or both. It's an issue I'm going to be filing away for awhile, and revisit later, though.